# Highcharts: multiple yAxes labels overlap

Tags: highcharts

I've got a chart where there are multiple yAxes and labels that overlap. I cannot instantiate them with different x values because I've got a UI that will switch the axes on and off, so that would leave weird spacing to one of the labels. I want to use formatter to detect if the label is not a first label and then change the x value then, but I have trouble finding how to change the value in formatter callback. Below is my code

```
{
        title: 'Count',
        gridLineDashStyle: 'Dash',
        gridLineColor: '#e8ebef',
        showFirstLabel: false,
        labels: {
          enabled: true,
          align: 'right',
          x: 5,
          y: 15,
          style: {
            fontFamily: fontFamily,
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: '#8596a5'
          }
        },
        opposite: true,
        allowDecimals: true,
        min: 0,
        minRange: 2 // Ensures flat charts don't show line at the bottom
      },
      {
        title: 'Cost',
        gridLineDashStyle: 'Dash',
        gridLineColor: '#e8ebef',
        showFirstLabel: false,
        labels: {
          enabled: true,
          align: 'left',
          x: 5,
          y: 15,
          style: {
            fontFamily: fontFamily,
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: '#8596a5'
          },
          formatter: function() {
          if ( this.isFirst ) { console.log("first") }
            this.attr({ x:44 })
          }
        },
        allowDecimals: true,
        min: 0,
        minRange: 2 // Ensures flat charts don't show line at the bottom
      },
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please recreate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Both of your yAxis should have order in which you want to show them.YAxis needs to be stacked.  Use

```
yAxis:0, //for first series 
yAxis:1  //for second series
```

I Will add a fiddle in few mins.